# Configuring and running a Phoenix Framework application

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang, elixir, elixir-mix

I can run my application from the terminal using `mix phx.server`. I decided to create an Elixir project in *IntelliJ* and move the project files there. My configuration of the Elixir Plugin can be seen below:

[image]

This causes the following message to appear:

> Shall I install Hex? (if running non-interactively, use "mix local.hex --force") [Yn]

This does not happen in the terminal since I have already installed it.

The command executed by IntelliJ is:

```
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/bin/erl -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.9.0-rc.0/lib/elixir/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.9.0-rc.0/lib/ex_unit/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.9.0-rc.0/lib/mix/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.9.0-rc.0/lib/logger/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.9.0-rc.0/lib/eex/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.9.0-rc.0/lib/iex/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/mnesia-4.16/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/compiler-7.4.2/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/asn1-5.0.9/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/runtime_tools-1.13.3/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/xmerl-1.3.21/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/os_mon-2.5/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/debugger-4.2.7/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/erts-10.4.2/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/ftp-1.0.2/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/parsetools-2.1.8/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/erl_interface-3.12/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/stdlib-3.9.2/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/erl_docgen-0.9.1/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/wx-1.8.8/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/megaco-3.18.5/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/tools-3.2/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/public_key-1.6.7/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/et-1.6.4/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/dialyzer-4.0.1/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/eunit-2.3.7/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/hipe-3.19/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/syntax_tools-2.2/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/snmp-5.3/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/diameter-2.2.1/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/ssh-4.7.7/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/crypto-4.5.1/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/sasl-3.4/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/edoc-0.11/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/ssl-9.3.2/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/kernel-6.4/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/eldap-1.2.8/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/inets-7.0.8/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/tftp-1.0.1/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/observer-2.9.1/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/common_test-1.17.3/ebin -pa 
/home/user/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.0.3/lib/reltool-0.8/ebin -noshell -s elixir start_cli -elixir ansi_enabled true -extra /home/user/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.9.0-rc.0/bin/mix phx.server
```

How should I properly configure IntelliJ to run my app?

Answer (score 3):

You should check what version of Elixir is used in your terminal and by IntelliJ.
For example, you can use ASDF backed Elixir in the project, while IntelliJ uses system-wide Elixir installation.

Check which Elixir (and Mix) versions are used by the IntelliJ inside your project.

Comment: I only use ASDF, (`$(asdf where elixir 1.9.0-rc.0)/bin/mix hex` works fine, so how do I make IntelliJ use that instead of `elixir/1.9.0-rc.0/lib/mix` that it is probably using?

Comment: Probably inside project settings - project SDK: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KronicDeth/intellij-elixir/master/screenshots/project_settings/Project.png